# List files which are transferred by sftp

Tags: shell-script, ksh

Can we list the files which are transfered via sftp be listed ?

Comment: From... a shell script that initiated the transfer? From a log file somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about auditing of files transferred, then this can be done if you reconfigure your `sshd` configuration then you can make it log entries via `syslog`

eg

```
Subsystem   sftp    internal-sftp -f AUTH -l INFO
```

Remember to restart `sshd` after changing this file.

Now I can run a session to my server:

```
% sftp test1
Connected to test1.
sftp> ls
myfile       
sftp> get myfile
Fetching /home/sweh/myfile to myfile
/home/sweh/myfile                             100%    8     5.1KB/s   00:00    
sftp> ^D
```

And we can see all this activity in the logs (on CentOS this is in `/var/log/messages`)

```
May  7 11:14:05 test1 internal-sftp[5610]: session opened for local user sweh from [10.0.0.137]
May  7 11:14:07 test1 internal-sftp[5610]: opendir "/home/sweh"
May  7 11:14:07 test1 internal-sftp[5610]: closedir "/home/sweh"
May  7 11:14:10 test1 internal-sftp[5610]: open "/home/sweh/myfile" flags READ mode 0666
May  7 11:14:10 test1 internal-sftp[5610]: close "/home/sweh/myfile" bytes read 8 written 0
May  7 11:14:11 test1 internal-sftp[5610]: session closed for local user sweh from [10.0.0.137]
```

These lines show the login, the `ls` command (`opendir`) and the `get` command (`open`).

It now becomes possible to audit `sftp` activity.